# Use PHP to detect which htaccess user signed in?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm constructing an upload so people I know can send me files securely, and with ease. But I want to design it just so, that when one of my friends sign in with *their* sign-in (it's going to an `.htaccess` login), I can establish that in PHP and log their file into a database associated with their account.

In short, I need PHP to be able to detect who is signed in so I can pass that data to a database.

Is there any possible way of doing that?

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` or phpinfo(32); every time you have a similar question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be able to get the user name the user signed in with from the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` variable after they've successfully signed in.

Comment: From the PHP manual: "As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent someone from writing a script which reveals the password for a page that was authenticated through a traditional external mechanism, the PHP_AUTH variables will not be set if external authentication is enabled for that particular page and safe mode is enabled. Regardless, REMOTE_USER can be used to identify the externally-authenticated user." We use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` on many of our pages and it works.

Comment: It does say it on the page that advocates `PHP_AUTH_USER`. I added my two cents about `REMOTE_USER` as to be another option/cover the special cases of external authentication. Link: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Chalk it up to a documentation difference between the two pages (since [this doc page doesn't have it](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) )...

Answer (score 7):

You'd want `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` to retrieve the username and password, assuming you mean a regular "basic authentication" login, as done by `Require valid-user` settings in .htaccess.

more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Answer (score 7):

Something that worked for me:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']
```

Please try the above. In general, one can do "`print_r($_SERVER)`" and hunt out the parameter one is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can read it from `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following variables give you the derise information:

**PHP_AUTH_USER:**
When doing HTTP authentication this variable is set to the username provided by the user.

**PHP_AUTH_PW:**
When doing HTTP authentication this variable is set to the password provided by the user.

```
 echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
 echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to open up an old task, but running PHP 5 with Apache 2.2 and this is the variable that works for me:

```
$_SERVER['USER'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but i solved it this way:

```
function getRemoteUser()
{
    foreach (array('REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER', 'REMOTE_USER', 'PHP_AUTH_USER') as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            $ret = $_SERVER[$key];
            if (!empty($ret)) {
                return $ret;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My solution pays respect to REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER', 'REMOTE_USER' and 'PHP_AUTH_USER'. It will return the first successful finding.