# AJAX using user and password parameters handles in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, passwords

I send AJAX request with 4th and 5th parameters user and password, how i can get value from this parameters in PHP?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("GET", "url", true, user, password);
```

Comment: related - don't forget to use SSL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145132/how-safe-is-it-to-send-a-plain-text-password-using-ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP to detect which htaccess user signed in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787261/use-php-to-detect-which-htaccess-user-signed-in)

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php